# Caching a dynamic JSON file on the server

Tags: php, json, caching

I'm using PHP to create a JSON file that is then queried as part of an AJAX request. At the moment this is taking a good few seconds, which is far too long, especially given that this is in closed development so there are no simultaneous requests right now.

I've noticed the delay is similar to the one when I try to load the JSON directly in the address bar. The data doesn't need to be constantly updated - even once every 12 hours would do.

My question is: is it possible to cache this data on the server side to speed up the AJAX requests? If so, how would I go about it?

Happy to post any relevant code, but I figured this question was quite abstract.

Comment: Slap [memcached](http://memcached.org/) somewhere in your system or [varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/) in front of it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would go about achieving such a caching system:

1. On a JSON request, I would use the file_exists() function to see if my cache.json file exists, if not, create one. (Good practice but only really relevant for the first run).  Proceed to generate the JSON and write the result to the file before outputting to the HTTP stream.
2. If the file exists, use PHP's filemtime() function to determine how old the file is, if it's older than 6 hours (or whatever you choose), re-open the file for writing and re-generate the JSON data for storage before outputting it to the HTTP stream.
3. If the file exists but is was last modified in the last 6 hours, simply output the file contents and don't bother generating any JSON this time around.

I hope this helps get you on the right path!  That's probably how I would approach it, without employing the use of MySQL or anything like that.

Good luck.